# Simple authentication for java ee 7 web app

Tags: java, postgresql, authentication, primefaces

I am developing a JavaEE7(Postgres, Glassfish, Primefaces) web app for which I need a simple identity management and authentication. Something simple like identity management from seam2(seam-gen).
I only need User, Group, Role and "Remember Me". An administrator should be able to create users ...  from the app. User is also required for createdBy and updatedBy fields.

I checked Picketlink but I found it a bit overkill for what I need.
I also checked Apache Shiro, but I am not sure if it's appropriate for managing users, roles and group directly from the app.

Any suggestion for a solution or a framework is Welcome

Thanks

Comment: If its really that basic its probably less effort to roll one on your own based on JAAS rather than to try and work in some existing framework.

Answer (score 1):

I evaluated picketlink and apache shiro. Picketlink is heavy for the application type I am developing.
I finally used apache shiro. The tutorial from BalusC was very helpful.
[Apache Shiro, is it ready for Java EE 6? (a JSF2-Shiro Tutorial)](http://balusc.blogspot.be/2013/01/apache-shiro-is-it-ready-for-java-ee-6.html)

and

[Securing Your ADF Applications Using Apache Shiro](http://www.jobinesh.com/2013/02/securing-your-adf-applications-using.html)